# Where are the extractors located?

Tags: youtube-dl

I am trying to modify one to two extractors, but I can't seem to find them on my Mac and I cannot find any information as to where they are located.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You may as well bite the bullet and start with the [complete source code](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/), study its file structure, then work on modifying that. That will also help you if you end up wanting to submit a patch to the main project.

Comment: @bright-star I have been trying to understand how to install it from source and I don't struggle cloning the source or whatsoever, but where I do struggle is the fact that I do not know how to proceed once it is cloned. Could you point me into the right direction please?

Comment: It looks like according to their [instructions](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/#developer-instructions) you can just run `python -m youtube-dl` to run the local source copy. Also, [there is a nice section on modifying and adding extractors](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/#adding-support-for-a-new-site).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find all extractors in the [`youtube_dl/extractor` subdirectory](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/tree/master/youtube_dl/extractor) in the source code.

For more information on how to add extractors, [consult the documentation](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#adding-support-for-a-new-site).